# How can I hide a div using cookies after an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to show a notification on my website and when a visitor click on the link I want to hide the notification for 30 days using cookies.

I've tried the following code but the problem is that the cookie is not kept and when I reload my page I can still see the notification.

```
<div id="disablenotification" class="container">
   <p>my message <a href="#" onclick="DisableNotification()">Got it!</a></p>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
       function DisableNotification(){
           days=30;
           myDate = new Date();
           myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
           document.cookie = 'DisableNotification=Accepted; expires=' + myDate.toUTCString();

           if ($.cookie("DisableNotification") === "Accepted") {
               $("#disablenotification").hide();
           }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here are the jquery CDNs I am using to accomplish this :

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your function DisableNotification anywhere.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
       function DisableNotification(){
           days=30;
           myDate = new Date();
           myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
           document.cookie = 'DisableNotification=Accepted; expires=' + myDate.toUTCString();

           if ($.cookie("DisableNotification") === "Accepted") {
               $("#disablenotification").hide();
           }
        }
        DisableNotification(); //Call the function
    });
});
```

Comment: this is not the issue, the function is called on the onlick.